# Input data into a 2nd cell, based on the value of a 3rd cell? (Like "conditional formatting")

Tags: excel, formatting, formula

B1 is a checkbox. If checked B1=1. A1 can range from 0 to 10. If B1 is checked I want A1 to automatically = 10. Exactly like conditional formatting would turn it green. I cant put the formula =IF(B1=1,10,"") into A1 though because I need to be able to input other values in A1 without erasing the formula. I need to be able to reuse the sheet multiple times.

Ex.

```
    A   B
1  10   x
2   9
3  10   x
4   4
```

Comment: Not without vba.  If one uses a different column for user input than the desired output then they can use a formula to decide which to use in the output, otherwise it will need to be vba in a worksheet_change event. Theoretically, if one only wants the appearance of 10 they could use Conditionl Formatting to use a custom format of `"10";;;` that would mask the actual value.  But if any formula refer to that cell it will produce the actual number and not the `10` that is seen.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott commented, you'd need to use VBA to do exactly what you're asking. A work-around, though, would be to add a third column with:

```
=IF(B1="x",10,A1)
```

In this case, Column A would be the user-inputted number, Column B would be your "x", and Column C would give the final output: 10 if B has "x", and the number from A otherwise.